# Homebrew Error. Directory in path with a slash. Have edited my $PATH but one remains that I can't locate/

Tags: linux, path, homebrew

Having run $ brew doctor I am receiving the following error below. I know this is a $PATH issue and have edited my ~/.bashrc file and my ~/.bash_profile files. There are none left where I can see /usr/bin/.

Is there anyway I can locate where this offending  /usr/bin/ is located?

```
Warning: Some directories in your path end in a slash.
Directories in your path should not end in a slash. This can break other
doctor checks. The following directories should be edited:
/usr/bin/
```

Comment: Not that I don't believe you, but `echo $PATH` and show us it's not there

Answer (score 3):

You need to restart your terminal window for those changes in ~/.bashrc and ~/.bash_profile to take effect. Hopefully the solution is as simple as that.